# Notify Google Search about updated sitemap

Tags: google-search, sitemap.xml

For Google search engine in my robots.txt file I got the line

```
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

If I updated the file sitemap.xml, how would I notify Google about it and make it crawl my site again?

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place for this question.

Comment: Did you check Google’s documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Google's Webmasters tool here => https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en
Find your site in the list of sites you own (if you have added it) or add it.
Once added if you click on the site to manage properties, you will see menu options on the left hand side that says "Crawl->Fetch as Google".
Or wait for Google to crawl your site in its own scheduled time!

Comment: wait for Google to crawl your site in its own scheduled time > You mean it will crawl every page based on frequency that I put in sitemap.xml file  for each page or Google has very own scheduled time

Comment: Here's Google's document on their crawl frequency https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34439?hl=en